# Reading values from json files into a node.js file

Tags: mysql, json, node.js

i was asked by my senior to establish connection into database, but rather than hardcoding the values to creating connection, he asked me to store the values which are required to establish connection in a .JSON file and asked me to get the values into node.js file

This is my json code

```
{
    "values" : {
        "host" : "localhost",
        "user" : "root",
        "password" : "root",
        "database" : "node"
    }
}
```

This following code has HARDCODED the vlues to establish connection

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var con  = mysql.createConnection({
    host : "localhost",
    user : "root",
    password : "root",
    database : "node"
});

con.connect(function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log("Connected!");
    var sql = "INSERT INTO details (name, prof) VALUES ('grijan1', 'student')";
    con.query(sql, function (err, result) {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log("1 record inserted");
    });
  });
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create **config.json** file where  store db connection information.

```
{
    "host" : "localhost",
    "user" : "root",
    "password" : "root",
    "database" : "node"

}
```

In node.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var configPath = './config.json';
var parsed = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync(configPath, 'UTF-8'));



var con  = mysql.createConnection({
    host : parsed.host,
    user : parsed.user,
    password : parsed.password,
    database : parsed.database
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You put that JSON data into a new file and you load in a new var :

```
var cnx = require('./file.json');
var con = mysql.createConnection(cnx.values);
```

Answer (score 0):

Create config.json file into your application containing above json.
Then use following

```
var config = require('./config.json');
var con = mysql.createConnection(config.values);
```